# MS Word Script to Return Text Under Specified Headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA script in MS Word that will iterate through a structured document (the doc uses standard Word layout styles), find any normal text under any level 4 heading with the title "Top," copy that text, then paste it under a level 2 heading titled "Highlights" that is located towards the beginning of the document. All of these headings already exist so I do not need the script to create them. Essentially, I am trying to compile text from these "Top" sections into one overall highlights section at the start of my document without having to go to each and manually copy/paste to my desired location.

The document has a table of contents that was autogenerated based on the existing headings as well as several tables that I inserted directly via the "Tables" pane under the "Insert" tab of the ribbon. Not sure if that makes any difference.

This is the script I've been working with but it keeps returning errors saying that the specified headings are not found.

```
Sub CopyTextUnderTopHeadings()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Specify the Level 4 heading text to find
    Dim level4HeadingText As String
    level4HeadingText = "Top"  ' Replace with the actual text
    
    ' Find the target Level 4 heading
    Dim level4HeadingRange As Range
    Set level4HeadingRange = FindHeading(doc, level4HeadingText, "Heading 4")
    
    ' Check if the Level 4 heading was found
    If level4HeadingRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Level 4 heading not found: " & level4HeadingText, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find the target Level 2 heading text where the text will be pasted
    Dim targetHeadingText As String
    targetHeadingText = "Highlights"  ' Replace with the actual text
    
    ' Find the target Level 2 heading
    Dim targetHeadingRange As Range
    Set targetHeadingRange = FindHeading(doc, targetHeadingText, "Heading 2")
    
    ' Check if the target heading was found
    If targetHeadingRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Target heading not found: " & targetHeadingText, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Process text under the found Level 4 heading
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim topText As String
    Dim copyText As Boolean
    copyText = False
    
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        If para.Range = level4HeadingRange Then
            ' Found the Level 4 heading, start copying text
            copyText = True
        ElseIf para.Style = "Heading 2" Then
            ' Found a Level 2 heading, stop copying
            copyText = False
        ElseIf copyText And para.Style = "Normal" Then
            ' Copy the normal text under the Level 4 heading
            topText = topText & para.Range.Text & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next para
    
    ' Paste the extracted text under the target heading
    If Len(topText) > 0 Then
        targetHeadingRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf & topText
    End If
End Sub

Function FindHeading(doc As Document, headingText As String, headingStyle As String) As Range
    ' Search for the specified heading text and style in the document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        If para.Style = headingStyle And Trim(para.Range.Text) = headingText Then
            ' Heading found, return its range
            Set FindHeading = para.Range
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next para
    
    ' Heading not found
    Set FindHeading = Nothing
End Function
```

I'm working in Windows 10 with Office365. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Tried script above, was expecting it to compile text from specified headings under another specified heading, but instead got a "heading not found" error

Comment: Why aren't you using Word's built-in [Find function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.style) to get the headings? If you don't know the syntax just record a macro. To get the text under a specific heading use there is a [predefined bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks) to get the heading level. The bookmark can be used from the range returned by Find.